# how to extract data from table in docx file and converte it to dataframe ARABIC DATA

Tags: python, dataframe, python-docx

I am trying to extract data from tables from word file .docx and convert it to dataframe using python.
Note: it arabic  text so i am using encoding ("utf-8")

Until now  i am able to get the .docx file and get the table (it have 13 columns) but i am not able to display the text.

Where is the error in my code ?

## code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import docx
        
         
document = docx.Document(path)
table = document.tables[0]
print(table)
        
data = []
        
for row in table.rows:    
    text = (row.cells[0].paragraphs[0].text.encode('utf-8'))
    data.append(text)
    print(data)
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

result:

```
[b'']
[b'', b'']
[b'', b'', b'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa']
[b'', b'', b'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa', b'']
[b'', b'', b'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa', b'', b'\xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xaa\xd8\xad\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x84\xc2\xa0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n']
[b'', b'', b'\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xb7\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa', b'', b'\xd9\x81\xd8\xb1\xd8\xb9\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xaa\xd8\xad\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a\xd9\x84\xc2\xa0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n', b'']
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove the `.encode('utf-8')`, this is why your result is not readable.

---

Second, you're only accessing the first column of each row (`row.cells[0]`).

You need to add another `for loop` to go through the columns, like so :

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    data.append([])
    for col_index in range(13): # Loop through columns 
        cell_text= row.cells[col_index].paragraphs[0].text
        data[row_index].append(cell_text)
```

Comment: i tried your answer it go through all the cells but it display this `[[b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'']]`  where as the real data is a ARABIC text

Answer (score 0):

```py
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd
document = Document('test.docx')

tables = []
for table in document.tables:
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            if cell.text:
                df[i][j] = cell.text
    tables.append(pd.DataFrame(df))
print(tables)
```